# Best setup for 5.1 speakers in room

Tags: home-theater, speakers, television, audio, sounds

I've got a 5.1 speaker system and I need guidance to place the speakers(5 sub-woofer/speaker and 1 main-woofer).

I heard that, for best experience there are specific guidelines for placement.
Like,

1. **The distance between each speakers**
2. **Height from ground level.**
3. **Distance from seats, etc.**

Below diagram shows the space of my room. 
[image]

Comment: A 5.1 system has five speakers and a sub  - center, front right, front left, rear right, rear left and a sub woofer.  Your diagram shows 7 spots for speakers.  ??? Henry is correct in his answer.    You would be better served asking at a home theater forum where they go into depth on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there are guidelines for how to place the speakers. E.g. here is a [Dolby 5.1 placement guide](http://www.dolby.com/us/en/guide/surround-sound-speaker-setup/5-1-setup.html). But the short answer is A, B, C, F, and E in your diagram, if you have to pick from those exact spots.

Also note that some higher-end stereos have a calibration feature that will use a microphone and test tones to detect the placement of each individual speaker, and can correct for some non-optimal placements. If you have a stereo that is capable of that you can rely on that to fix some problems. Few people are lucky enough to have a room 100% dedicated to a home theater, so it is common to have non-optimal placement due to other factors (doors, other furniture, etc).